# How to divide screen space between ImageView and TextView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I need to put `ImageView` and below it should be textview. I have done this by using text and image in `RelativeLayout`. Everything is ok , but I need to give more space (2/3)  to `ImageView` . How can I do this ? 
Thx in advance .

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adPlaceholder" >
    <ImageView  
        android:id="@+id/image_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_main"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: u can take a linear layout inside relative layout with weight proprety

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `LinearLayout` is more appropriate for your situation
You can use `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` and `android:weightSum="3"`

Then you can give `android:layout_weight="2"` to the `ImageView` and `android:layout_weight="1"` to the `TextView`

The final XML code after update

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/rel_lay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_above="@+id/adPlaceholder"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="3" >

<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/image_first"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting something, or is that your image occupy more space to your text, you can do this type:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rel_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adPlaceholder"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to put a `LinearLayout inside ReletiveLayout` and set weightsum to the inner LinearLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rel_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adPlaceholder"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also note that the `layout_weight of ImageView is 1 out of 3` making in 2/3 of the parent and that of `TextView is 2 out of 3` making it cover 1/3 of parent.